# Gradle Could not find method compile() for arguments

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, subproject

i have a hello world full screen android studio 1.5.1 app that i added a gradle/eclipse-mars subproject to. no other files were modified except for adding include ':javalib' to settings.gradle. adding a [project lib dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies):

```
project(':app') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':javalib') // line 23
    }
}
```

to the root build build file and running gradle from the command line , gets:

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidMain\build.gradle' line: 23
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'AndroidMain'.

  > Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':javalib'] on org.grad
  >   le.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@46
  >   3ca82f.

[adding the java plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23800903/51292) to the root build file did not help.

i don't think it's in the [wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23627293/51292).

both the root project and the added subproject have the gradle wrapper.

any pointers will be appreciated.

thanks

edit: for clarification, the root build file is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    task hello << { task -> println "I'm $task.project.name" }
}

project(':app') {
    dependencies {
        //compile project(':javalib') // causes problems
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the app build file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "acme.androidmain"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile project(':javalib') // use :javalib:jar?
    //testCompile project(':javalib')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

edit: the whole purpose of this exercise is to get core java code into an android project. currently the core code is a standalone gradle/eclispe project. i have a batch in the android project that does a gradle -p standaloneprojectdir/ jar and copied the jar into libs/.

i just though there would be an easier way other than to publish the jar and get it from a repository since this all done on my pc.

it would be nice to have all the code live and just do a build :(

edit: as per [RaGe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745574/rage)'s suggestion, here is a [virgin android studio project](https://github.com/rtayek/Virginandroidstudioproject) and a [virgin gradle/eclipse project](https://github.com/rtayek/virginjavaproject.git). no editing has been done to these files. you mission should you choose to accept it is to get the android app to easily access the java project classes (i.e. new Library(); in MainActivity.onCreate() will compile and run). i don't care where the java project lives. ideally, both sources would be *live* in both ide's.

atempting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17490233/51292) fails also. says: > Could not find :virginjavaproject, but directory does exist.

edit: what actually worked was RaGe's pull request to the [virgin android project](https://github.com/rtayek/Virginandroidstudioproject).

Comment: Java plugin is not appropriate for an android project, but you should have the Android plugin somewhere, which adds the compile configuration. Did you create the project using Android studio?

Comment: Can you show your project folder structure please

Comment: yes. there is one in the app build file. please see edit.

Comment: root/ has app/ and javalib/ - root and app were created by android studio, javalib is a clone of an standalone gradle/eclipse project that i added by hand.

Comment: Did you add javalib to settings.gradle?

Comment: yes, settings,gradle in root/ has:  include ':app'
include ':javalib'

Comment: You already have a compile javalib in the app build.gradle, why repeat it in the root build.gradle?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777525/how-to-solve-could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments-file-collection/68421448#68421448

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have

```
compile project(':javalib')
```

in your `:app` project, you don't have to also inject the dependency from your root build.gradle. If you still want to do it from the root `build.gradle`, the correct way to do it is:

```
configure(':app') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':javalib') // causes problems - NOT ANYMORE!
    }
}
```

the [virgin android studio](https://github.com/rtayek/Virginandroidstudioproject) head is what worked.

Comment: i do have that compile in the app build file. removing it does not help.

Comment: removing the compile from he app build file, and replacing my project() { ...} with your configure() { ...} in the root build file still fails with the compile line. where is the doc for the configure?

Comment: can you show your settings.gradle please? Configure [doc is here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:configure(java.lang.Iterable, groovy.lang.Closure))

Comment: setting.gradle in root/ is: include ':app'
include ':javalib', settings.gradle in javalib/ is: rootProject.name = 'javalib'. thanks for the doc,

Comment: there is no `:` in project names in settings.gradle. See examples here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: yes, there is no ':' in the doc. but generating a new app with android studio puts: include ':app' in the setting.gradle file.

Comment: Can you try deleting settings.gradle in javalib/ ?

Comment: removing the ':'s in settings.gradle does not help.

Comment: commenting out the code in settings.gradle gets: Error:(20, 0) Project with path ':app' could not be found in root project 'AndroidMain' using project(){}

Comment: using comfigure(){} it says: Error:(27, 0) Project with path ':javalib' could not be found in root project 'AndroidMain'. (with or wothout the ':'s

Comment: I meant comment out the settings.gradle in the javalib folder, sounds like you commented out the root settings.gradle ?

Comment: yes, there's a coment in the file: To declare projects as part of a multi-project build use the 'include' method.  both project(){} and configure() {} still get : Error:(27, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Comment: If you could upload a stripped down version of your project to github, I can try to help you out. Your code files aren't necessary, just the folder structure and all gradle files.

Comment: see pull request I submitted to your github project

Comment: @etech Can you post your issue as a new question please

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 files named "build.gradle".
make sure you have copied your "compile code" in the build.gradle file that is inside **"app"** folder

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [@peter-niederwieser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84889/peter-niederwieser):

> The build script is mixing up buildscript dependencies (i.e. dependencies of the build itself; typically this means Gradle plugins) with regular dependencies (i.e. dependencies of the code to be compiled/run). The latter need to go into dependencies { ... }, not into buildscript { dependencies { ... } }. Everything but the classpath dependencies are regular dependencies.

Also have a look at this: [Could not find method compile() for arguments Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796404/could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments-gradle).

Comment: the dependency is not in the buildscript.

Answer (score 0):

Simply paste this on build.gradle(Project:"Your prject name")

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

  buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
}
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
     }
 }

   allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but with my own library. The way to correctly compile was:

```
compile project(path: ':MyLib')
```