# How to fix the error "Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs']" fundamentally?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, node-modules, deprecated

I am posting the question after having a look at all similar questions and answers.

Here are the questions I studied.

[Could not find method compile() for arguments Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796404/could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments-gradle?rq=1)

[Gradle Could not find method compile() for arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958886/gradle-could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Maybe, you might wonder that it's a duplicate question but in my case, it's not.
Let's see how it is.
First, here is the code snippet that the error comes from:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}
```

This code is from the file: `node_modules/react-native-geocoder/android/build.gradle`

Now let me show you what error shows up.

```js
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Project-root/node_modules/react-native-geocoder/android/build.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-geocoder'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
```

All answers say that you need to replace `compile()` method with `implementation()` method because `compile()` method is deprecated from `gradle 7.0` and currently I am using `gradle 7.4`.
But editing files inside `node_modules` folder is not a good idea as everybody knows.
And it's `react-native` project and the package in issue is `react-native-geocoder`.
I browsed `react-native-geocoder repo` but it's achieved by its owner and read-only now. So I cannot submit PR to the repo.

https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder

I would like to discuss about any wiser answer.
What is a fundamental answer to fix this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: You should configure <project-name>/android/app/build.gradle' and NOT the <project-name>/android/build.gradle'.   Also compile method has been deprecated from gradle 4.0 and completely removed from gradle 7.0 so use implementation instead of compile.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

react-native-geocoder compile issue:

You can fix this issue by replacing `compile` with `implementation` in node_modules/react-native-geocoder/android/build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}
```

changed to

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}
```

Compile method has been deprecated from gradle 4.0 and completely removed from gradle 7.0

Comment: That's what I already found. But editing node_modules will raise the issue once I or someone else reinstall the node_modules. Right? So I am seeking for another solution.

Comment: @VecopWall see `patch-package` to customize packages locally; it is ideal for situations like this.

Answer (score 7):

This can be resolved / bypassed by adding:

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    if(project['name'] == 'react-native-geocoder'){
        project.configurations { compile { } }
    }
}
```

to your project's build.gradle file.

Reference: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3242#issuecomment-1145423942

Answer (score 3):

Muhammad solution is correct, there's just a problem, when you run yarn install and/or delete node_modules the library is going to go back to its previous state and you will have to change it again, to prevent this you need to use `patch-package`:

After doing the modification you need to run this on your terminal:

```
npx patch-pacakge name-of-the-library-you-modified
```

Example:

```
npx patch-pacakge react-native-geocoder
```

This is going to create a file inside the `patch` folder, you need to commit this file.

The next time you delete `node_modules` or run `yarn install`, the library is going to return to its previous state so you need to apply the patches, you do this with just:

```
npx patch-package
```

Notice I didn't add the library name this time, this is because you could have several patches for different libraries and this is going to apply all of them.

Going beyond:
If you don't want to have to remember to do `npx patch-package` each time you run `yarn install`, you can add this command in the `scripts` section of your `package.json`, like this:

```
 **package.json file**

 {
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
  "scripts": {
      "postinstall": "patch-package",
     ...
  }
  ...
 }
```